# html height won't set to 100%

Tags: html, css, height

I'm trying to implement Sticky Footers, but when I go to set the height of html, body, the surrounding asp.net form, then check in Firebug, they are clearly not expanding to 100%. Can anyone explain why these are coming up short?

My page:

http://www.craftonhills.edu/Current_Students/Student_Life/Clubs/Badminton_Club.aspx

Thank for your time.

Comment: it looks fine, what is coming short?

Comment: I agree with sweettea. It looks fine, other than perhaps the footer is not all the way on the bottom of the page? Otherwise, my only question is why you have a form element surrounding almost the entire markup of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to set height 100% on `<div id="container" class="container_12"...>` or another suitable enclosing element.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response!  Have a blessed day!